# Snowflake: File format with RECORD_DELIMITER with chars + new line

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a problem with creation of file formats in snowflake where I can create the file format but I can't make him do what I need.
Basically I have CSV file that is coming in a weird format.
mainly the record encapsulation is both the new line (\n) and a few more characters before (#@#)

So basically I'm trying to create a file format with this something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT  META.CSV_TEST
    TYPE                            = CSV
    SKIP_HEADER                     = 0
    SKIP_BLANK_LINES                = TRUE
    FIELD_DELIMITER                 = '^^{'
    RECORD_DELIMITER                = '#@#\\n'
    FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY    = '"'
    EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL             = TRUE
    NULL_IF                         = ('NULL', '-')
;
```

But this does not do what I want and basically the \n stays in the records.
I tried also '#@#\n' but no such luck.

Any idea how I could create such a file format?

According to the documentation, if I understood correctly, this should work, but maybe my error is more basic.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html

I do not get errors when creating the file format simply in the output of the content I still see the \n

For example:

```
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught 
{"RECORD_CONTENT":"OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(\n 'BU_ID',
```

Another thing I try is just to remove the #@# and then this works fine but the #@# becomes part of my contents and I would rather avoid that.
I can do some post-processing after loading the file but I would really like to do this in the file format just not being able to do it.

Thank you for any insights best regards

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  I am having the same issue. Seems Snowflake don't really care about these issues and have developed nothing to handle these.

Comment: No fix or feedback I honestly did not open an issue with them. I think I just went with a post processing to cleanup the records